# insert element in array at specific index

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, optimization

I was asked in a interview to insert a element at a index(the index was given) in the most optimized way.

I have already tried this

```
  /* Make room for new array element by shifting to right */
            for(i=size; i>=pos; i--)
            {
                arr[i] = arr[i-1];
            }
             arr[pos-1] = num; /* Insert new element at given position and increment size */ 
             size++;
```

Is there any better way than this to do?

Comment: Using `System.arraycopy` to do the shift could be a bit faster (see also https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,int,java.lang.Object,int,int) ).

Comment: Your code is incorrect - move the size++ to before the “for”, otherwise you are losing the last element.

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following optimization:

-put iterator on last element's position and iterate from right to left until you reach `pos` and apparently maintaining variable `last` which keeps the last new encountered element
-on every iteration, check if current element is equal to `last`, if yes then skip it, if no then copy current element to `current_index+1` and assign current element to variable `last`
-finally assign new element to `pos`

As we see, this approach is based on assumption that comparison is cheaper than shift (i.e. it is better to do comparison on every iteration and shift element from time to time, instead of shifting ALL elements from `pos` till end) but I'm not quite sure on what extent this assumption is true - considering that moving an element would require two assembly operations involving memory (from memory addr. to register and back to new memory addr.) vs. one operation involving memory (from memory addr. to register) and one arithmetic operation for comparison

The worst case is when there are no equal elements adjacent to each other - in that case we will do both comparison and shift on every iteration.